# Runtime Return array size Error Python

Tags: python, arrays, parameters, differential-equations, odeint

I am trying to solve a simple differential equation using odeint function. It is giving an error with matching size of array. I think my **initial_condi** is not matching with the **equation** function. I can't figure it out where actually the error is. Blow is the error and code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**RuntimeError: The size of the array returned by func (1) does not match the size of y0 (3)**

```
from scipy import *
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from operator import itemgetter
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from pylab import *
from itertools import product
import itertools
from numpy import zeros_like
import operator

initial_condi = [1, 1, 1]
t_range = arange(0.0,60.0,1.0)

def equation(w, t):

    T,I,V = w
    dT= V*I*10.24-T*1.64

    return  dT


result_init = odeint(equation, initial_condi, t_range)

plt.plot(t, result_init[:, 0])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As your state vector has 3 components, the return value of the ODE function also needs to have 3 components, the derivatives of `T,I,V`. You only provided `dT`, but should `return [dT, dI, dV ]`.